# Chrome Extension Context Menu Items Limit

Tags: google-chrome-extension, contextmenu, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Although the docs are pointing out:

*The maximum number of items that can be added to the top-level browser action context menu is menus.ACTION_MENU_TOP_LEVEL_LIMIT, **but you can add any number of items to submenus**.*

I am only able to add 1000 submenu items to the Chrome Extension context menu.

I don't want to create a UI additionally, because the context menu is really handy for my use case. The user is working in a code editor and can look up code syntax string values via the context menu and can add the value at the position of the cursor where the user right-clicked.

Do you know of such limitations or a workaround besides using an additional UI element?